# Assigning To Pointer After Freeing It

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I am looking at the following code from the book "Programming Interviews Exposed":

```
bool deleteStack( Element **stack ){
      Element *next;
      while( *stack ){
            next = (*stack)->next;
            free( *stack );
            *stack = next;
      }
      return true;
}
```

I am not that familiar with C++ or C, so this may be a silly question, but wouldn't assigning something to a pointer after freeing it cause a problem?

Comment: Nothing wrong here, as @simonc says. You are not freeing the content of \*stack, but the content of the memory that \*stack points to. Your LOCs, with regular variables, are no more wrong that doing: a=1; a=0; /* see this as a free() of a */ a=2;

Comment: If I was given this in an interview for C++... I would say "why no smart ptrs?"

Comment: You don't free a pointer. You free what the pointer is pointing at.

Comment: @PinkElephantsOnParade: If you are implementing a container (like a list) you usually don't use smart pointers as the ownership symantics are usually well defined and self contained within the container. There are two basic forms of automated memory management containers and smart pointers.

Comment: @LokiAstari Fair enough. No reason to pull out the big guns when not necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example, `*stack` is a pointer.  It is perfectly safe to free the memory it points to then assign the pointer to a new variable.

The only thing that would be unsafe would be to dereference `*stack` after freeing it.

```
free( *stack );
next = (*stack)->next;
```

would be incorrect as the memory pointed to by `*stack` has unpredictable content (and may no longer even be accessible to your process) after the `free` call.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's OK. You don't actually "free a pointer" doing this:

```
 free( *stack );
```

but you free some dynamically allocated memory pointed to by the pointer `*stack`. When you do:

```
*stack = next;
```

you make the pointer to point to a different block of memory, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Is safe to do that. When you look at something like `(*stack)` you can think about it like 'the pointed by stack'. Since `free` is expecting a pointer to a memory location, you're freeing the 'memory slot' pointed by stack from your process virtual memory.
This means the space for the memory address (ie, the pointer) is still available and you can re-use it.
Also, I think this is probably useful, when you use the arrow notation `->` you're using two different notations in C/C++ simplified for its common use. So, this: `stack->next` is the same as this: `(*stack).next` 
Good luck.

Comment: `this: stack->next is the same as this: (*stack).next` - The notation OP was actually using was `(*stack)->next`, because stack is a pointer to a pointer to an element so OP had to deference before using the `->` operator.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just explaining cause it might be he's problem. Is not an easy pointer to read at the beginning, so I thought it might be useful to fully understand the arrow notation. 
But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning `NULL` to pointer variable after freeing it is just to keep a hint in the code to identify if dereference happened for freed address.

If we dont assign NULL to freed pointer, behaviour is undefined(50% chance for crash and remaining chance for heap corruption) if we derefence that freed pointer variable. But if it is `NULL` setted it will surely crash. If heap get corrupted it will be difficult to identify the bug rathen than a crash at one place.

Please dont think like freed pointer will never be dererenced in your code. If a project is maintained for long time, then there will be chance of adding (or modifiying) code wrongly.